# File Sharing fails with Android 11

Tags: java, android

I tried to upload text file in my phone(Android 11) to Gmail, Dropbox, Google Drive...

But, all failed.

I wrote `android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"` tag in the manifest file.

TargetSdkVersion is `29`.

Download file from above apps works fine. Only upload does not work.

It works for my old phone.(below Android 10)

I think, problem is caused by `"Android 11 open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"`

This is my code. How can I solve this problem?

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    else
        path = Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED;
    path = path + "/myFolder"; // /storage/emulated/0/myFolder
    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdir();
..........................................................   
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    File file = new File(myFolder + "/" + "test.txt");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, null);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
        startActivity(chooser);
```

Comment: You wanna share a file and then you use mkdir to create a directory? I dont see the logic. Also you are not checking the return value of mkdir.

Comment: `Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);` That will not work. Use FileProvider to obtain an uri and serve your file.

Comment: I want to share files in that directory. So, I first made directory to store files when app starts.

Comment: `Only upload does not work.` ? Upload? Where?

Comment: `So, I first made directory to store files when app starts` Can be. But please do not post irrelevant code. And certainly not in this way. Confusing. You did not post the code for downloading or storing files. Good. As that is irrelevant too.

Comment: You can omit the check for media mounted as now adays it is always mounted.

Comment: I mean sharing does not work for everywhere.

Comment: For everywhere? What do you mean? We know already that sharing fails. And i told you why.

Comment: `Uri.fromFile()` has effectively been banned since Android 7.0. You should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException`. Use `FileProvider` to make your content available to the other app.

Comment: `Uri.fromFile() has effectively been banned since Android 7.0. ` For ACTION_VIEW yes. But for ACTION_SEND only since version 10 i believe. @CommonsWare.

Comment: @blackapps: The OP is using Android 11, based on the question. More importantly, a fairly substantial percentage of Android devices run Android 10 or higher. So, even if you are correct, and Android was not checking `Intent` extras for `file` `Uri` values on older devices, you still need to use `FileProvider` (or something like it), to support modern devices.

Comment: Yes i know that all. And look at comment #2 please @CommonsWare.